# Animate on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login button at the middle of a page. After I click it a modal window opens, I press sign in and after that the location url is appended with login's container hash, the page reloads, and I want the page to animate to a certain point.

```
window.onload = function(){
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == "#container"){
        $('body').animate({scrollTop : 290});
    }
};
```

Unfortunately it only works on desktops. On tablet it only goes to hash(doesn't matter if it's ios or android). I tried with $('body, html') aswell. I also tried with window.scrollTo(0,290);

Comment: It's probably not refreshing the page on your tablet, therefore the "onload" event won't fire again. Try refactoring it into a function and call it after you press the Sign In button.

Comment: The event is firing, used an alert to check it.

Comment: Can you alert the hash and share the output? `alert(window.location.hash)`

Comment: @Bogdan, Event will fire..But does it fire every time you change the hash ? I doubt..

Comment: @AndreFeijo I alerted the hash, it's #container

Comment: @RayonDabre I use location.reload() after I change the location so yes, the event will fire everytime.

Comment: Aah..It is better to listen it instead of `reload` => `window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);
`

Comment: iOS seems to don't scroll the body, it moves the viewport. This causes some undesired effects when jQuery tries to interact with it. The solution is to scroll a div rather than the body of the document.